# UITextField: backspace doesn't delete the first character

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield, string-formatting, backspace

I have a UITextField with a formatted string.

I can't figure out why a backspace press works fine for every character deletion except the first character?

My code:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
    formatter.groupingSeparator = " "
    
    let textString = textField.text ?? ""
    guard let range = Range(range, in: textString) else { return false }
    let updatedString = textString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    let completeString = updatedString.replacingOccurrences(of: formatter.groupingSeparator, with: "")
    
    guard let value = Double(completeString) else { return false }
    numberFromTextField = value
    
    let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value)) ?? ""
    textField.text = formattedNumber
    
    return string == formatter.decimalSeparator
}
```

A gif with the problem behaviour: [CLICK](https://cln.sh/nnL3vK)

Where is my error hides?

Comment: You have two `guard`. I guess that you don't pass the guard of `Double(completeString)` if `completeString` is empty (because of the delete) trying to remove the last digit. Add `guard !completeString.isEmpty else { return true }`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with breakpoints on every return value? I think it should hint to the root of the problem.

Comment: @Larme thank you very much. You're right, I missed it. Now I can clear the textField. You can post it as an answer, I'll pick it as best one. If I don't bother you, can you take a look at one more problem: when textField is cleared I want other cells to be = 0. For now they show a calculation for the last number that was in active textField. GIF: https://cln.sh/QzJxUw How to show 0 when its cleared after deletion?

Comment: It depends on what's the logic to populate the others... And you didn't specify it...

Comment: @Larme ok, I got it. I will try to find the reason by myself. If not succeed then create a new question and let you know. Post you answer on my initial question, I'll pick it as the best. Cheers!

Comment: @artexhibit Not related to your question but you can simply do `textField.text = formatter.string(for: value)`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you, corrected, it's much more shorter then :)